# Serialize vs Using Database for storing multiple links of a parsed page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I have to parse a html page from a website say http://example.com.
On this page there are multiple links, i need to store those links with title.

I was thinking what is best approach to save those links. Should i serialize them ?. For example in Ruby On Rails

```
@page.links = {'links' => {'title1' => "link1", 'title2' => "link2", 'title3' => 'link3'} }
```

or should store into Sql Database.

```
PagesLinks(link_id, page_id)
```

I am just creating an api end point, that will consume a url and parse it to store its links. Another another api point will retrieve the url and its links.

Comment: That largely depends on how you are going to use those links afterwards

Comment: I am just creating an api, that will consume a url and parse it to store it link.
Another another api point will retrieve the url and its links.

Comment: Well I think it depends on preferences. I would probably store them in relational manner (having one DB row per link) and then link them to the `page` row. But serializing and storing them in a JSON format in postgresql also seems like a reasonable way. What DB are you using?

Comment: I have a choice, i can use either of Postgresql or mysql.

Comment: A serialized attribute is easier to implement at the beginning, but harder to work with and error-prone (e.q query for specific links, changing the structure). A dedicated database table is more work upfront, but IMO the cleaner solution. Btw your example would break if there are multiple links with the same title, but different URLs on a page. I think a good answer depends on how you want to read and use the links later on (Hint: always optimize for reading)...